# Cruise control merging?

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I had successfully extracted the compilation log present in my IDE into some one xml file very well. So in order to merge it I had mentioned in my `ccnet.config` file inside the publisher task using the `<merge>`
section.

But when I force my build, I am able to get the `output.xml` file correctly but an
error is thrown in `ccnet.config` window that it is unable to merge as this file is currently used by some other process.
Please see below:

> [VSAT:ERROR] Publisher threw
>   exception:
>   ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.CruiseC
>   ontrolException: Unable to read the
>   contents of the file: C:
>   \ThreePartition\outp ut.xml --->
>   System.IO.IOException: The process
>   cannot access the file 'C:\ThreeP
>   artition\output.xml' because it is
>   being used by another process.

Can you suggest any method by which merging can be done successfully?
I have pasted the whole `ccnet.config` file below.

```
                <project name="VSAT">
                <sourcecontrol type="filtered">
                 <sourceControlProvider type="filesystem">
                 <repositoryRoot>C:\ThreePartition</repositoryRoot>
                 <autoGetSource>true</autoGetSource>
                  <ignoreMissingRoot>false</ignoreMissingRoot>
                 </sourceControlProvider>
                <exclusionFilters>
                 <pathFilter>
                <pattern>C:\ThreePartition\wrSbc750gx_ThreePartition\**</pattern>
                </pathFilter>
                <pathFilter>
               <pattern>C:\ThreePartition\*.txt</pattern>
                </pathFilter>
                <pathFilter>
               <pattern>C:\ThreePartition\*.xml</pattern>
                </pathFilter>
            </exclusionFilters>
           </sourcecontrol>
          <triggers>
           <intervalTrigger name="continuous" seconds="240"
            buildCondition="IfModificationExists" />
         </triggers>
        <tasks>
        <nant>
       <executable>C:\Nant-0.85\bin\NAnt.exe</executable>
       <buildFile>nant.build</buildFile>
       </nant>
        </tasks>
       <publishers>
      <merge>
        <files>
           <file>C:\ThreePartition\output.xml</file>

          </files>
        </merge>
       <xmllogger logDir="C:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\server\DF2.0-CI
       \Logfiles" />

      <email from="BuildAdmin@server.com"
      mailhost="smtp.servermail.com" includeDetails="TRUE">
   <users>
     user name="Maddy" group="buildmaster"
     address="Mymail@server.com"/>
    </users>
 <groups>
 <group name="buildmaster" notification="always"/>
 <group name="developers" notification="change"/>
 </groups>
 </email>
 </publishers>
 </project>
 </cruisecontrol>
```

---

I had just placed the publishers section below for the better view

```
           <publishers>
      <merge>
     <files>
              <file>C:\ThreePartition\output.xml</file>                 
         </files>
    </merge>
    <email from="BuildAdmin@server.com" mailhost="smtp.server.com" includeDetails="TRUE">
            <users>
          <user name="Maddy" group="buildmaster" address="Maddy.@server.com"/>
            </users>
            <groups>                        <group name="buildmaster" notification="always"/>
                    <group name="developers" notification="change"/>
            </groups>
    </email>
```

Comment: Uh, can you do an Edit and remove the breaks from the code section? This is very hard to read. Thanks

Comment: Hi lucero,i had updated the question below.Please have a look at it

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas:

- Eliminate other obvious applications that would be writing to that file: other CCNet projects, other CCNet instances (e.g. are you maybe running the service and something from the command line?), or perhaps your source control.
- If you're not attached to NAnt, try MSBuild and see if you get the same error.  If all you're doing is compiling, you can pass the .sln or .csproj as a parameter directly to MSBuild.
- Make sure you're on the latest version of CCNet - they regularly publish what I would consider fairly major bug fixes regularly.

Answer (score 0):

What is says: the question is which process has open your xml while CC.net is trying to merge -- perhaps Process Explorer could be useful? Perhaps it works if you copy the xml output to a separate file and merge that.